# cannot find symbol method d(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

Tags: java

When I compile the code below error occurs:

```
canot find symbol
 location: interface org.apache.commons.logging.Log    Log.d(TAG,"JSON parsing error - fix it:" + e.getMessage());`
```

This is my code:

```
//convertJSONtoArray

private void convertJSONtoArray(String rawJSON){
    try {
        JSONObject completeJSONObj = new JSONObject(rawJSON);
        String json = completeJSONObj.toString();
        Log.d(TAG,json);
        JSONObject results = completeJSONObj.getJSONObject("results");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d(TAG,"JSON parsing error - fix it:" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you developing on an Android platform?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible reasons:

**1. You are using Android**

In that case replace the import for Apache Commons Logging Log with:

```
import android.util.Log;
```

**2. You are developing in normal Java environment**

Your import statement at the top of your class includes Apache Commons Logging Log, but the code was definitely not written for Commons Logging.

For Commons Loggig is should look like this:

```
private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(NAME_OF_YOUR_CLASS.class);

private void convertJSONtoArray(String rawJSON){
    try {
        JSONObject completeJSONObj = new JSONObject(rawJSON);
        String json = completeJSONObj.toString();
        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug(TAG,json);
        }
        JSONObject results = completeJSONObj.getJSONObject("results");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug(TAG,"JSON parsing error - fix it:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: already import the apache common logging but still now i get error

Comment: `Log.d` and `TAG` looks like he's using code that uses [the Android `Log` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html).

Comment: @murali: what nfechner tries to tell you is that you should **not** import the commons logging `Log` class. Is this code for an Android project? Then import the relevant Android `Log` class instead. If it *isn't*, then you will need to adapt it to some other Log-API (such as Commons Logging).

Comment: @JoachimSauer Not exactly, but you are right. It smells a lot like Android code. I also put up a comment on the question, to get clarification.

Comment: iimport the android package but still now i getting cannot find symbol ..log.debug error

Comment: If you are indeed on Android (and you should answer that question first!! See comment under question), you only have to switch the import statement and leave the rest of your code as it was before.